# R Language Definition: indexing a named vector using dollar sign

Tags: r

Characters can be used to index a named vector in the following way:

```r
v <- c(a=9, b=8, c=7)
v[["a"]]  # Returns: 9
```

I am reading the *R Language Definition*, [§ 3.4.1 Indexing by vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors), which seems to say that the dollar sign (`$`) can be used to access the contents of a named vector:

> R allows some powerful constructions using vectors as indices. We shall discuss indexing of simple vectors first. For simplicity, assume that the expression is `x[i]`. Then the following possibilities exist according to the type of `i`.
>
> [...]
>
> - Character. The strings in `i` are matched against the names attribute of `x` and the resulting integers are used. For `[[` and `$` partial matching is used if exact matching fails, so `x$aa` will match `x$aabb` if `x` does not contain a component named `"aa"` and `"aabb"` is the only name which has prefix `"aa"`. [...]

So I tried to use `$` in the following way:

```r
v <- c(a=9, b=8, c=7)
v$a
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error in v$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What does this mean? I must be misunderstanding the excerpt from the *R Language Definition* above.

Comment: Indexing using `$` is possible with lists `v <- list(a=9, b=8, c=7)`. It is not possible to index a vector using `$` sign.

Comment: @RonakShah If that's the case, then why does the text say "We shall discuss indexing of simple vectors first"?

Comment: the main thrust of that section is talking about x[i] usages, it's a bit odd for mention of $ to happen off-handedly there. the behavior of $ described there applies where $ does, which is not for atomic vectors (as (often) constructed by c() (see ?is.atomic for details) and mentioned in your error message).  the behavior described would apply to lists and I believe environments, e.g.

Comment: The focus of that section is on indexing **by** vectors. It is not mentioned that we are indexing vectors, lists or anything else.

Comment: @RonakShah but in `x$aa` `aa` is a name, not a vector. so the reference does seem out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the introductory part of section [3.4 indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing),
whose first subsection is the paragraph that you mentioned ([3.4.1 Indexing by vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors)), it is specified that:

> The form using $ applies to recursive objects such as lists and pairlists. It allows only a literal character string or a symbol as the index.

> Applying $ to a non-recursive object is an error."

In your example, you are indexing a non-recursive object using $. And because the vector being indexed is not recursive, you got an error.

You can test if an object is recursive using the function `is.recursive`. Note that an environment object is also recursive.

```
v <- c(a=9, b=8, c=7)
x <- list(a=8, b=3)
y <- pairlist(a=5)
e <- as.environment(x)

is.recursive(v)
# [1] FALSE
is.recursive(x)
# [1] TRUE
is.recursive(y)
# [1] TRUE
is.recursive(e)
# [1] TRUE
```